# Cannot get Dropzone.js to send additional data

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, dropzone.js, razor-pages

I'm using Dropzone.js with .net core 3.1. I can get it to call my controller action, bt I cannot get it to send any additional data with the request.

This is my form:

```
<form action="/api/photos/"
          class="dropzone needsclick dz-clickable"
          id="image-upload"
          method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="eventId" value="1"/>
        <div class="dz-message needsclick">
            <span class="note needsclick">
                Drop files here or click to upload.
            </span>
        </div>
    </form>
```

This is my Javascript:

```
<script>
            Dropzone.options.imageUpload = {
                dictDefaultMessage: "Drop files here or Click to Upload",
                addRemoveLinks: true, // Allows for cancellation of file upload and remove thumbnail
                init: function () {
                myDropzone = this;
                    myDropzone.on("sending", function (file, xhr, data) {
                data.append("message", "hello world");
                        console.log(data);
                    });
                    myDropzone.on("success", function (file, response) {
                console.log("Success");
                        myDropzone.removeFile(file);
                    });
                }
            };
    </script>
```

This is my controller endpoint

```
public async Task<IActionResult> PostPhoto(List<IFormFile> file)
        {
            ..code removed..
        }
```

So as you can see I have a hidden field in the form, which should have sent the data along with the request, and I also have tried to append a value to the form data via the JS, but either it's not sending or I can't find it. I've looked in the network panel of dev tools and can see the images being sent but nothing else. Or how would I find it in the controller if it was being sent? I've spent ages on this, which is slightly annoying, please help!

Comment: Looks like your controller accept only file, and you are trying to send JSON data with           enctype="multipart/form-data", you have to use enctype="application/json" to send regular JSON data.

Comment: I removed the enctype from the form, but still no luck - according to the 'tips' section on the dropzone site, "Dropzone will submit any hidden fields you have in your dropzone form. So this is an easy way to submit additional data. You can also use the params option.". Neither of these methods are working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add eventId to url parameter in form action, like this `<form action="/api/photos/1"`

Then update you controller action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/photos/{eventId:int}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostPhoto([FromRoute] int eventId, List<IFormFile> file)
    {
        ..code removed..
    }
```

Another solution with using `sending` event, like you do. But you need to add param to you contoller action. You append `message` in js, so your code will be like this:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostPhoto([FromForm]string message, List<IFormFile> file)
    {
        ..code removed..
    }
```

Comment: Thank you - I get it. The second method worked, by using the sending event in JS. Another way that worked - as the documentation said it would - is to have the hidden field in the form, the key being to modify the controller signature to accept the value as per the 2nd method also.